# How to create a JWT for use with Apple Music

Tags: ruby, jwt

Im trying to create a developer token that is a ES256 JWT to use for Apple Music authentication. ([Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/AppleMusicWebServicesReference/SetUpWebServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017625-CH2-SW1))

Im using ruby and the JWT gem but after creating the token I get a 401 error when authenticating with Apple Music

```
    require 'jwt'

    payload = {:iss => 'CapExdTeam', :iat => '1497335982', :exp => '1513112982'}

    priv = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGTAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBHkwdwIBAQQgU208KCg/doqiSzsVF5sknVtYSgt8/3oiYGbvryIRrzSgCgYIKoZIzj0DAQehRANCAAQfrvDWizEnWAzB2Hx2r/NyvIBO6KGBDL7wkZoKnz4Sm4+1P1dhD9fVEhbsdoq9RKEf8dvzTOZMaC/iLqZFKSN6
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"
    ecdsa_key = OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new(priv)

    token = JWT.encode payload, ecdsa_key, 'ES256', { :kid => "CapExedKid", :alg => "ES256" }
    puts token

    `curl -v -H 'Authorization: Bearer #{token}' "https://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/us/songs/203709340"
```

Im using the sample private key to simulate 429 error just for illustration purposes

Comment: having the same problem

Comment: I have pretty much the same code. Could be setting the epoch time for the exp field wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I used this script and it works perfectly
https://github.com/pelauimagineering/apple-music-token-generator

Comment: Hey thanks man I've been working on a solution for this for days and was about to consume one of our developer technical code level supports and just ask them how they would do it. I do not have much experience outside of swift so I was lost with all these other languages. Thanks again!!!

Comment: What a pleasure: your description of how to do this is simple, direct and works! What a pleasure after looking at various options that assume way to much. Thank you many times.

Comment: Original question (and myself by finding it) are looking for a Ruby solution.  Provided link is in Python, and works great...Just need a Ruby solution.

Comment: @DanDevine the code in the question should work, provided you ensure `priv` `iat` `exp` `kid` and `iss` are all set to the proper values.  I had success with my own key, using `iat = (Time.now - 1.minute).to_i` and `exp = iat + 12.hours`

Comment: Ok... I actually worked through this, and needed to debug BOTH of the scripts at the same time.  The Python JWT library silently adds the 'typ': 'JWT' modifier to the headers...  The Ruby JWT library does not.  If you manually add the 'typ':'JWT' to the header hash, it works as it's supposed to.  The question now becomes...which of the libraries is correct?

Comment: On some platforms, I had trouble with this line: `key = OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new(keyfile.read)`.  It was giving me an error `OpenSSL::PKey::ECError: unknown curve name nested asn1 error`.

I was able to verify this error outside of ruby with `openssl ec -in file.p8`

I worked around this issue by converting the .p8 private key Apple provided to PEM, on a platform that worked for me, by running `key.to_pem`

Comment: I am using this script but getting 401 user unauthenticated error

Answer (score 4):

Based on @DanDevine's answer, here's a more Ruby/OO approach:

```
require "openssl"

# Example: 
#
#  token = AppleMusic::Token.new(key_id: "...", team_id: "...", keyfile: File.new("lib/assets/AuthKey_xxxxxxx.p8"))
#  token.auth_token
#  token.auth_header
# 
module AppleMusic
  class Token
    attr_reader :key_id, :team_id, :keyfile

    # Keyfile should be an IO type that responds to `read`
    def initialize(key_id:, team_id:, keyfile:)
      @key_id = key_id
      @team_id = team_id
      @keyfile = keyfile
    end

    def auth_token
      @auth_token ||= fetch_auth_token
    end

    def auth_header
      "Bearer #{auth_token}"
    end

  protected

    def fetch_auth_token
      header = {
        typ: "JWT", # Must be specified; not in documentation
        alg: "ES256",
        kid: key_id
      }

      body = {
        iss: team_id,
        iat: Time.now.to_i,
        exp: Time.now.to_i + 43_200 # 12hrs
      }

      JWT.encode(body, auth_key, 'ES256', header)
    end

    def auth_key
      key = OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new(keyfile.read)
      key.check_key
      key
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I wrote a Medium tutorial for using MusicKit with RubyMotion. I credited this answer and @coreyward for the JWT instructions & code. https://medium.com/@kevlaw/search-for-apple-music-with-rubymotion-part-2-800240c58ea2

Answer (score 3):

It's now also possible in pure Swift!

You first have to create a MusicKit identifier and a private key using [this guide from Apple](https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/devce5522674). Then a token can be easily created using [Swift-JWT from IBM](https://ibm-swift.github.io/Swift-JWT/) in pure Swift.

It's more or less just an invocation of the SwiftJWT API:

```
let teamId = "yourTeamID"
let keyId = "yourKeyID"
let keyFileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath:"/pathToYour/key.p8")

struct MyClaims: Claims {
    let iss: String
    let iat: Date?
    let exp: Date?
}

let myHeader = Header(kid: keyId)
let myClaims = MyClaims(iss: teamId, iat: Date(), exp: Date() +  24 * 60 * 60)
var myJWT = SwiftJWT.JWT(header: myHeader, claims: myClaims)

let token = try! myJWT.sign(using: .es256(privateKey: try! String(contentsOf: keyFileUrl).data(using: .utf8)!))
```

I created a simple example and a command line tool using the Swift Package Manager: [SwiftJWTSample](https://github.com/klaas/SwiftJWTSample/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working Ruby implementation.  Call with your keyId and teamId, provide access to your private key file and go.

```
class AppleMusic

    @auth_token
    @validity_start
    @validity_end


    def initialize(keyId, teamId, options ={})
      appleKeyId = keyId
      appleTeamId = teamId
      @validity_start = Time.now.to_i
      @validity_end = Time.now.to_i + 43200  # 12 hours in seconds...

      # Build up the headers
      header = {
          'typ' => 'JWT',           # MUST BE SPECIFIED...  Apple doesn't tell you this!
          'alg' => 'ES256',
          'kid' => appleKeyId
      }

      # Build up the payload
      body = {
          'iss' => appleTeamId,
          'iat' => @validity_start,
          'exp' => @validity_end
      }

      # This should be installed manually on the server somewhere
      # TODO:  Add some protection around the file's existance, set the name & location
      # as some type of configuration key.
      file = File.read('lib/assets/AuthKey_xxxxxxx.p8')
      key = OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new(file)
      key.check_key

      @auth_token = JWT.encode(body, key, 'ES256', header)
      @auth_token
    end

    def auth_token
      @auth_token
    end

    def auth_header
      "Bearer #{@auth_token}"
    end

    def validity_start
      @validity_start
    end

    def validity_end
      @validity_end
    end
 end
```