# Apple MusicKit Developer Token

Tags: ios, token

I am following Apple's guide to musickit and I have been looking for a long time to resolve the following step:

[Guide apple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUyPF.png)

I've already created the token.

[Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUbLu.png)

But I do not know what to do next where it says: "sign it with your MusicKit private key (see Create a MusicKit Private Key). Then encrypt the token using the Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA) with the P-256 curve and the SHA-256 hash algorithm. Specify the value ES256 in the algorithm header key (alg)".

I do not know how to encrypt ECDSA or where.

I do not know where to put the private keyword.

Comment: How did you get the token? i'm trying to do the same by following this guide : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/AppleMusicWebServicesReference/SetUpWebServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017625-CH2-SW1 but i don't see the certificates . do i need to enroll in apple developer program? thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a JWT for use with Apple Music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44514221/how-to-create-a-jwt-for-use-with-apple-music)

Answer (score 5):

If you're still curious about this then [pelauimagineering's example](https://github.com/pelauimagineering/apple-music-token-generator) which worked perfectly for me.

If you don't already have:
Download **pip**, then two libraries: **pyjwt** & **cryptography**

On terminal do:

```
$ sudo easy_install pip
$ sudo pip install pyjwt
$ sudo pip install cryptography
```

- Clone pelauimagineering's repository and edit the `music_token.py`
  file replacing the secret variable with the .p8 key you downloaded.
- Replace the keyId with the value you'll find at developer.apple.com
  under certificates > keys, and then click the key of the app you
  downloaded the .p8 file for and you'll see the key Id there.
- Lastly, replace the teamId variable on the .py file with the 10 digit key found on your developer account at developer.apple.com/account and then click the membership tab and you'll see your 10 digit Id. Remember you need a developer token to do this which costs $99/year.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the sample code to generate the token for NodeJS:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('AuthKey_1234.p8').toString(); // file downloaded when you created your key
const jwtToken = jwt.sign({}, privateKey, {
  algorithm: 'ES256',
  expiresIn: '180d',
  issuer: '1234V73RKG', // Your team ID
  header: {
    alg: 'ES256',
    kid: '1234VPQXH4' // ID from the Key with MusicKit permissions
  }
});


console.log("token:", jwtToken, "\n");
```

The JWT node module does all the hard work for you.

Comment: Hey I tried this code, but it just doesn't work for me, it still says unauthorised. I've opened a question about this but haven't got any answers that work. Does this still work in 2019?

Comment: @Tometoyou it should. Are you using the proper Team ID and Key ID? you also need an Apple Music membership.

Comment: You need apple music membership? I don't have that. I thought you can access their stuff without getting a user token? And I am using the proper team and key ID from my developer account.

Comment: @Tometoyou from docs: `MusicKit JS lets users play songs from Apple Music and their Cloud Library inside your JavaScript app.` - how did you expect a user without membership to be able to play songs? As far as I know it is required, never tried without membership.

Comment: Go to Authenticate Requests on this page: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/getting_keys_and_creating_tokens. It has a separate bit for "personalised requests", implying that you can still get data without sending a user token. Besides, you can play preview music on the Apple Music site without having to log in. I only want the 30 sec preview music... Please could you try accessing something without a user token and tell me if it works for you?

Comment: At time I'm writing this code does not work anymore. Before July 19 it worked.

Comment: Yes, it's not working anymore. It results in 401 always

Answer (score 0):

You can generate and sign  your token from [here](https://apple-developers-token-gen.herokuapp.com/). It is an apple developer token generator with an open source code, that can be found on github. Also you could find some documentation for it in this [link](https://medium.com/@mikopos/apple-developers-token-generation-2a90250c3d13).

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the steps up to this point you should have downloaded a p8 file to `/Users/username/Downloads/AuthKey_KEYID.p8`

The below steps will help you create the `[developer token]` which will be 3 base64 strings concatenated together by `.` (a dot), e.g. `base64str.base64str.base64str`.

For the first base 64 string, take the 10 chars that are the KEYID and replace them in this command:

```
echo -n '{"alg":"ES256","kid":"KEYID"}' | base64 | sed s/\+/-/ | sed -E s/=+$//
```

We'll refer to this output as `BASE64STRING1`. If you see a `%` at the end of the line don't copy it, and same goes for the rest of the base64 strings output.

Now you need timestamps, enter `date +"%s"` and we'll call that `X`. Then use the Calculator to add 7888500 (for 3 months) we'll call that `Y`. The docs state it must be less than 6 months from the the time the server receives a request.

Now you need your developer ID which you'll find in the top right of the Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles page in the Dev center. Replace `DEVELOPERID`, `X` and `Y` in this command:

```
echo -n '{"iss":"DEVELOPERID","iat":X,"exp":Y}' | base64 | sed s/\+/-/ | sed -E s/=+$//
```

We'll refer to this output as `BASE64STRING2`.

Next with a dot between these 2 strings, and replace KEYID in the p8 file and fix the path, enter:

```
echo -n "BASE64STRING1.BASE64STRING2" | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -sign /Users/username/Downloads/AuthKey_KEYID.p8 -out signature.bin
```

Next we will convert the `signature.bin` (See [here](https://github.com/madaster97/openssl-jws) for more info on this conversion):

```
openssl asn1parse -in signature.bin -inform DER > asn1
cat asn1 | perl -n -e'/INTEGER           :([0-9A-Z]*)$/ && print $1' > signature.hex
cat signature.hex | xxd -p -r | base64 | tr -d '\n=' | tr -- '+/' '-_'
```

Surprise, another base64 string: `BASE64STRING3`.

Now by joining the 3 strings with dots, you have your developer token, try it out with:

`curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer BASE64STRING1.BASE64STRING2. BASE64STRING3' "https://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/us/songs/1517622625"`

Result should be json of the song info.

You can now delete the `signature.bin` and `signature.hex` temp files created.

I managed this thanks to [this tutorial](https://techdocs.akamai.com/iot-token-access-control/docs/generate-jwt-ecdsa-keys) but it did not include the signature.bin conversion.